# What is the best way to design the attached image pattern on mobile

Tags: gui-design, mobile, user-behavior, android, mobile-application

[image: picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]
I have a button like the above 1st image. If I am pressing that button it will display the Stacked Action items like in picture 2. By pressing the any of the stacked Action button it will go to the next page  but its in a web application and I want the same design in mobile, so what is best approach or design for mobile?

Comment: @dan1111 i have edited the question for you please have a look

Comment: What are they stretching? I am guessing they are delaying something?

Comment: Action are "5 minutes","10 minutes","15 minutes",20 minutes and more" are the action if you press any one of that it will go to the next page. IS it clear enough?

Comment: @SteveD they stretching items are not delaying,There are action iteams or buttons asking if you want to do that for 5 min,10 min,15 min,20 min or you want to skip

Comment: @viewPagerSpecialist what do you actually mean by "stretching"? It has multiple definitions :-)

Comment: @SteveD its expanding when you tap on the  first picture

Comment: @viewPagerSpecialist Expanding time?

Comment: "5 minutes" is not an action.  What is the user doing?  I mean complete a sentence like "The user clicks on the image so that they can _______."  "They can then select how long they want to ______: 5 minutes, 10 minutes, etc."

Comment: Would "Extend" be a better word than "Stretched"?

Comment: Is this a workout app?

Comment: @SteveD, I assume this is related to physical exercise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't know the exact purpose of the button. But for this kind of options the dropdown seems to be unsuitable. Perhaps use a solution like

[Stretch for X min] [-5min or up arrow] [+5min or down arrow]
or 
[skip]

X is a variable and can be changed by the +/- buttons. It is easy to use and contains your 5 min step size. Additionally it is good to use at mobile devices and space efficent.

I think this solution implements your options properly and you can preset the most common duration for your users.

Comment: I should appreciate your analytical skills damn good..

Comment: Do u have linkedIN?